# How to setText in TextView inside onReceive method of BroadCastReceiver?

Tags: android

Basically I want to perform setText() feature of TextView class inside , BroadCaseReceiver . But I am not being able to implement this : I don't know

why ( `context.findviewById()` is not working ) , because `findViewById()` is part of Activity class and `context.toString()` is showing the reference of Activity( base activity ) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to below answer is here: [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
```

}
Now the fragment can deliver messages to the activity by calling the onArticleSelected() method (or other methods in the interface) using the mCallback instance of the OnHeadlineSelectedListener interface.

For example, the following method in the fragment is called when the user clicks on a list item. The fragment uses the callback interface to deliver the event to the parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Send the event to the host activity
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
}
```

Implement the Interface
In order to receive event callbacks from the fragment, the activity that hosts it must implement the interface defined in the fragment class.

For example, the following activity implements the interface from the above example.

public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

```
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article
}
```

}
Deliver a Message to a Fragment
The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with findFragmentById(), then directly call the fragment's public methods.

For instance, imagine that the activity shown above may contain another fragment that's used to display the item specified by the data returned in the above callback method. In this case, the activity can pass the information received in the callback method to the other fragment that will display the item:

public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

```
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article

    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

    if (articleFrag != null) {
        // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

        // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
        articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

        // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you have used concept of callBack () .

Answer (score 0):

Unless if the BroadcastReceiver is started programmatically inside the context of an Activity  e.g. Activity.onCreate(). For an ordinary BroadcastReceiver, it is very odd to access a UI element like TextView from it. You can only work with UI stuff from an Activity. Maybe you should reviewing the solution of which you're trying to apply. Even if you manage to do such a thing, it will have a wrong design.

Comment: sorry to say ... but i am doing something like 

i fetched something from internet using ( AsyncTask ) , now i want to send that data to TextView , so i am using broadcast_reciever to set the data which is fetched from internet .

Comment: you don't need the BroadcastReceiver then...do it all on the onPostExecute() method...of course, make sure you're doInBackground returns the data you need...then you perform the textView.setText() call from within the onPostExecute() that was designed specially for this case...it runs on the UIThread. It is the way do it.

Comment: you are true ... but now please think that i have a fragment inside that fragment i have a textView now ( without having fragment your answer Rocks ) but  now if i have fragment than how can i set my Text inside Fragment's_textView .

Comment: @user2147072 It will be better if you put your code what you tried, and what you want to do now, I think you just want to send data form async task to your activity, if I am correct then you dont need to use broadcast reciever for that.

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar please see this "you are true ... but now please think that i have a fragment inside that fragment i have a textView now ( without having fragment your answer Rocks ) but now if i have fragment than how can i set my Text inside Fragment's_textView ."

Comment: @user2147072 if you want to pass data form activity to fragment then take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private MyActivity myActivity;

public MyReceiver(MyActivity myActivity) {
    this.myActivity= myActivity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("", "Onrecieve ready to call");
            if(this.myActivity!=null)
            {
                this.myActivity.update();
            }
            // make update method is in your activity.
            // call function of your activity and change UI.
}
}
```

Comment: not nice, leaking an Activity in a BroadcastReceiver...Activities can die and the BroadcastReceiver would be leaking the reference of a dead activity...this is a typical case for applying the Observer Pattern.

Comment: if activity is dead.. Setting up text in `TextView` question does not arise. If activity is dead then unregister reciver

Comment: @Alecio , Wow its a great Answer , i never think like that . its a vote_up answer .